# Trouble with ssh command - wrong parameters getting passed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh

I would like to execute bunch commands using ssh on remote server and wanted to provide flexibility of getting server name and other information as arguments. Command printed on console works, but does not work when executed as a shell script. I have managed to build script so far using bash man page and researching various sites.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER=
USER=()
KEYFILE=()
PORT=()

while getopts ":s:u:k:p:" opt; do
      case ${opt} in
          s ) SERVER=$OPTARG ;;
          u ) USER=($OPTARG "@") ;;
          k ) KEYFILE=("-i" "$OPTARG" ) ;;
          p ) echo $OPTARG &&  PORT=("-p" "$OPTARG") ;; 
          \: )
              echo "Missing argument for option $OPTARG" 1>&2
              exit 1
              ;;
          \? )
              echo "Invalid Option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
              exit 1
              ;;
          *  ) echo "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
      esac
done

USER=(${USER[@]} $SERVER)
printf -v userIdPattern '%s' "${USER[@]}"

declare ssh_cmd=("/usr/bin/ssh" "${PORT[@]}" "${KEYFILE[@]}" "$userIdPattern"  )
echo "Ssh command ${ssh_cmd[@]}"

declare ls_cmd=("${ssh_cmd[@]}" "ls -al")
echo "ls command ${ls_cmd[@]}"
$("${ls_cmd[@]}" )
```

When executed like

```
./generalSetup.sh -s app4 -u me
```

I get response back

> ./generalSetup.sh: line 35: total: command not found

Message indicates ssh command is trying to execute output of ls command, but not sure how to pass different commands as a array.

Eventual goal is extract this as a function and execute bunch of commands on destination server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$("${ls_cmd[@]}" )` tries to execute the *result of* (standard output of) `"${ls_cmd[@]}"` - presumably including the `total` line from `ls`

Comment: @steeldriver I think you are right. Can you think of way out?

Comment: You just need to remove the outer command substitution I think - just `"${ls_cmd[@]}"` in place of `$("${ls_cmd[@]}" )`

Comment: @steeldriver, It helped. Thank you. If you want to post this as an answer with little explanation, I can accept it.